# Can not write to nfs mount despite r/w permissions in place

Tags: mount, nfs, read-only

Somewhat puzzled by the following and hoped there would be someone on here to advise:

```
[root@mybox02 ~]# mount | tail -1
mystor01:/spool1_fs1/ on /global type nfs (rw,addr=xx.xx.xx.25)
[root@mybox02 ~]# tail -1 /proc/mounts
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling
mystor01:/spool1_fs1/ /global nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=xx.xx.xx.25,mountvers=3,mountport=1234,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=xx.xx.xx.25 0 0
[root@mybox02 ~]# touch /global/testFile
touch: cannot touch `/global/testFile': Read-only file system
[root@mybox02 ~]#


[root@mybox01 ~]# mount | tail -1
mystor01:/spool1_fs1/ on /global type nfs (rw,addr=xx.xx.xx.25)
[root@mybox01 ~]# tail -1 /proc/mounts
tail: inotify cannot be used, reverting to polling
mystor01:/spool1_fs1/ /global nfs rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=xx.xx.xx.25,mountvers=3,mountport=1234,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=xx.xx.xx.25 0 0
[root@mybox01 ~]#  touch /global/testFile
[root@mybox01 ~]# ls -l /global/testFile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 17 11:13 /global/testFile
[root@mybox01 ~]#
```

I can not write to the nfs file system from mybox02 despite the fs being mounted r/w. There does not seem to be any issues when accessing from mybox01 and as far as I am aware both systems are configured identically, plus permission on the storage side seem to be correct as well as I have tried a different location, which ended up with the same result.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

C

Comment: Are the NFS server's export settings correct? Even though you mount as rw, the server can still have ro settings for that machine.

Comment: `mystor01` is NAS storage and as a result is fairly basic in that it doesn't give any NFS specific settings, it's just as simple as adding the hostname(s) under the relevant permissions section and applying.